# Android, How to display Snackbar without visible view?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am trying to show any SMS received in a snakbar even if the user was outside my application, so is it possible to display it ?

Here is my previous code using Toast:

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                    String message = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context ,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 150);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: in android if you want to give the user info or message you can use notification. and btw snack bar its not the best approach whe you try to give use information about new message

Comment: @Gujarat Santana Actually, I do not need to show whole message body, only numbers with pattern 4-6 digits will be displayed. It works fine with Toast, but it is hard for me to control toasts duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html

```
Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view.
```

You should use Toast or Notification in this case!